# React-Native, create dynamic string related to i18n

Tags: string, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [`react-native-i18n`](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) to develop a multi-locale app. In some strings I have to put a dynamic string like:

`var str = 'Hello dear '+ user.name +', good morning!'`

I don't want to define two params in languages json files (due to makes my code dirty and some langs are different in motion) to have such code:

`var str = lang.t('hello')+ ' ' + user.name + lang.t('goodMorning')`

I need a syntax like what we have in `Java` and `C#`:

**`var str = string.format(lang.t('helloMorning'), user.name)`**

///////////////
en.json:

**`{
   "helloMorning":"Hello dear %s, good morning!"
}`**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define your translations like this.

```
{
  "greeting": "Hello, %{name}. Good morning!"
}
```

And then in your render, pass parameters like this.

```
i18n.t('greeting', {
  name: 'Ali'
})
```

Answer (score 14):

use i18n hook

```js
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
```

define translation json

```js
{"greeting": "Hello, {{name}}.Good morning!"}
```

jsx

```js
{t('greeting', { name: "sumit" })};
```

Comment: in React i18n dynamic string support

Comment: This worked on my end